# WooCommerce Plugin - "hidden" css class and style override for Product Meta Box pricing;

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Problem: Product Div Tab - Regular Price and Sales Price not showing automatically because 'style = display:block' no longer being added to Div.

WooCommerce plugin - woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-
                           meta-box-product-data.php

Hi all,

I am banging my head trying to figure out how WooCommerce is no longer adding the following to the html div in the 'General' tab of the Product meta-box :

"style = display: block"

```
<div class="options_group pricing show_if_simple show_if_external hidden" style="display: block;">
```

It allows the "Regular Price" and "Sales Price" fields to be shown. Coming into this project new, I do not know which plugins may be overriding WooCommerce's default functionality. The php for class-wc-
meta-box-product-data.php is this:

```
echo '<div class="options_group pricing show_if_simple show_if_external hidden">';
```

So it is defined there as having a "hidden" class attribute, but obviously something was adding in the display:block to make sure it is visible. Could you tell me please where WooCommerce may be or may not be adding that display:block attribute? I could not find any filters that were being used that were relevant to this.

Here is a picture of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: If the div is being hidden with inline styling it's most likely coming from javascript. So you should check your dev console for any errors.

Comment: thanks, I double-checked the console but no errors. did a scan of the js files for woocommerce and while I saw a hide functionality for the sales calendar I didn't see anything related to the "display:block " for the general product tab